# Dynamically pointing multiple domains to a single domain's subfolder with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In this example, I manage **`domain.com`**. Inside it, I have a store template in php that loads the selected store dinamically:

> - `domain.com/store1`
> - `domain.com/store2`
> - `domain.com/store3`

The nice urls are being generated by the `.htaccess` below. What's really being loaded in the back, is this:

> - `domain.com/store/index.php?store=store1`
> - `domain.com/store/index.php?store=store2`
> - `domain.com/store/index.php?store=store3`

Each store has internal links, such as these:

> - `domain.com/store1/catalogue`
> - `domain.com/store1/catalogue/instruments`
> - `domain.com/store1/catalogue/instruments/guitars`
> - `domain.com/store1/electric-guitar/1337`

It works exactly as expected. These are the `.htaccess` rules to make that work in **`domain.com`**. The `store` query string (`store1`, `store2`, `store3`) in each `RewriteRule` determines which store is being loaded:

```
# permalinks
RewriteEngine on

# errors
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php?error=404

# ignore existing directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]

#################################################

# store
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]{2,50})/?$ store/index.php?store=$1 [QSA,L]

# store: catalogue
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]{2,50})/catalogue/?$ store/catalogue.php?store=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]{2,50})/catalogue/([0-9a-zA-Z-]{1,75})/?$ store/catalogue.php?store=$1&cat=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]{2,50})/catalogue/([0-9a-zA-Z-]{1,75})/([0-9a-zA-Z-]{1,75})/?$ store/catalogue.php?store=$1&cat=$2&subcat=$3 [QSA,L]

# store: products
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]{2,50})/([0-9a-zA-Z-]{1,150})/([0-9]+)$ store/product.php?store=$1&slug=$2&id_product=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Now, here comes the tricky part. Some of the clients, would like to use their own domains, so that `store1.com/*` loads the same content of `domain.com/store1/*` (without using a redirect).

*Example:*

> - `store1.com` => `domain.com/store1/`
> - `store1.com/catalogue` => `domain.com/store1/catalogue`
> - `store1.com/catalogue/instruments` => `domain.com/store1/catalogue/instruments`
> - `store1.com/catalogue/instruments/guitars` => `domain.com/store1/catalogue/instruments/guitars`
> - `store1.com/electric-guitar/1337` => `domain.com/store1/electric-guitar/1337`

You get the idea.

All the domains (`domain.com`, `store1.com`, `store2.com`, `store3.com`) are configured in the same Apache Web Server environment (using virtual hosts).

The question is: **Can this be implemented in a `.htaccess` file in each one of the store's domain root path dynamically or inside the virtualhost `.conf` file? If so, how?**

Comment: It is most probably doable, but the exact implementation details may vary. What is the relation between domain name and store name (will it always be just .com appended, what if it is .co.uk, what if there is www. before store1.com, what if a request with unknown domain arrives...). Also, if you have access to apache configuration (.conf) files, you should not use .htaccess at all. And finally, you will probably be better off just handling all this logic in your web app code.

Comment: @DusanBajic thanks for the feedback. They won't use www., ever. The domain type can be anything though: `.com`, `.co.uk`, `.ec`, etc. It will be probably not possible to switch the `.htaccess` logic from the **domain.com** root, because everything is tied up in there, the solution should be -maybe- in the `.conf` files of the additional domains (?) Any ideas on where to start looking?

Comment: I assume the domain name, ie. `store1` in `store1.com` will be the required value for the `store` URL parameter, just as the "virtual directory" `/store1/` is now?

Comment: @MrWhite Exactly. Without the `store=store1` value, the template in `domain.com` wouldn't know which store to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure all your custom "store" domains (eg. `store1.com`, `store2.com`, etc.) are defined as `ServerAlias` in the `domain.com` vHost and so resolve to the same place as `domain.com`.

You can then rewrite requests for the custom store domain to prefix the URL-path with the *store-id* (the domain name) and then use your existing rules unaltered.

For example, a request for `store1.com/catalogue/instruments` is *internally rewritten* to `/store1/catalogue/instruments` and then processed by the existing rules as usual.

The following directives should go *before* the existing `# store` rules:

```
# Internally rewrite the request when a custom domain is used
#  - the URL-path is prefixed with the domain name
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.\w{2,4}$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}@%1 !^/([^/]+)/.*@\1
RewriteRule (.*) %1/$1
```

And that's basically it, although you may also decide to implement a canonical redirect - see below.

Explanation of the above directives:

- The first *condition* simply excludes requests for the main `domain.com` (which should already have the relevant *store-id* prefixed to the URL-path).
- `%{REQUEST_URI} !\.\w{2,4}$` - The second *condition* avoids rewriting requests for static resources (images, JS, CSS, etc.). Specifically, it excludes any request that ends in  - what looks like - a file extension.
- `%{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)` - The third *condition* captures the requested domain name before the TLD which is then accessible using the `%1` backreference later and used to prefix the URL-path. This assumes there is no www subdomain (as stated in comments). eg. Given a request for `store1.com` or `store2.co.uk`, `store1` or `store2` respectively are captured.
- `%{REQUEST_URI}@%1 !^/([^/]+)/.*@\1` - The fourth *condition* checks that the URL-path is not already prefixed with the domain name (captured above). This is primarily to ensure that rewritten requests are not rewritten again, causing a rewrite loop. This is achieved using an internal backreference (`\1`) that compares the first path-segment in the URL-path against the previously captured domain name (`%1`).
- `(.*) %1/$1` - Finally, the request is internally rewritten, prefixing the domain name to the requested URL-path.

---

#### Ignore existing files (may not be required)

> ```
> # ignore existing directories
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
> RewriteRule .* - [L]
> ```

You've not stated how you are referencing your static resources (images, JS, CSS, etc.), but you may need to modify this rule to also match requests for existing files. (Although the *condition* I added to the rule above may already be sufficient to exclude these requests.) For example:

```
# ignore existing directories or files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

---

#### Canonical redirect (optional)

You should also consider *redirecting* any direct requests of the form `store1.com/store1/catalogue/instruments` back to the canonical URL `store1.com/catalogue/instruments` - should these URLs ever be exposed/discovered. A request of the form `store1.com/store2/catalogue/instruments` will naturally result in a 404, so is not an issue.

For example, the following would go immediately after the `ErrorDocument` directive in your existing rules:

```
# Redirect to remove the "/store1" URL-prefix when the "store1.com" domain is requested.
# - Only applies to direct requests.
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}@%1 ^/([^/]+)/.*@\1
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]+)(/.*) $1 [R=301,L]
```

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

This is basically the reverse of the above rewrite, but applies to direct requests only. The check against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var ensures that only direct requests from the client and not rewritten requests by the later rewrite are processed.

---

## Summary

With the two rule blocks in place...

```
# permalinks
RewriteEngine on

# errors
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php?error=404

# Redirect to remove the "/store1" URL-prefix when the "store1.com" domain is requested.
# - Only applies to direct requests.
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}@%1 ^/([^/]+)/.*@\1
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]+)(/.*) $1 [R=301,L]

# ignore existing directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Internally rewrite the request when a custom domain is used
#  - the URL-path is prefixed with the domain name
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.\w{2,4}$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}@%1 !^/([^/]+)/.*@\1
RewriteRule (.*) %1/$1

#################################################

# store

:
: existing directives follow
:
```

Comment: This is the most comprehensive answer that works. Thanks!